# Build Apache rpm from tar ball on Rocky Linux 8.5

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, rpmbuild

im trying to build apache rpms from source tarball

OS is Rocky Linux 8.5 with all the prerequisites

Im running :

rpmbuild -tb -sign httpd-2.4.53.tar.bz2

and the error i get :

> ```
> error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
>    /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_md.so-2.4.53-1.x86_64.debug
>    /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_md.so
>    Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
>    /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_md.so-2.4.53-1.x86_64.debug
>    /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_md.so
> ```

i have tried configure && make without any errors

> ```
> configure: summary of build options:
>
>  Server Version: 2.4.53
>  Install prefix: /usr/local/apache2
>  C compiler:     gcc
>  CFLAGS:           -pthread
>  CPPFLAGS:        -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE
>  LDFLAGS:
>  LIBS:
>  C preprocessor: gcc -E
> ```

i have also tried different versions of httpd ( 2.4.48 to 2.4.53 )

i tried to extract the tar and run :

rpmbuild -bb with increased verbosity

i can build other rpms from tar, for example apr-1.7.0.tar.bz2

> ```
>  Provides: debuginfo(build-id) = a10b57a82a4f0f93a26b6f5f21824930e4768ee2 mod_ssl-debuginfo = 1:2.4.53-1 mod_ssl-debuginfo(x86-64) = 1:2.4.53-1
>  Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
>  Recommends: httpd-debugsource(x86-64) = 2.4.53-1
>  Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.53-1.x86_64
>  D:      execv(/usr/lib/rpm/check-files) pid 412641
>  D:      waitpid(412641) rc 412641 status 0
>  error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
>  /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_md.so-2.4.53-1.x86_64.debug
>  /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_md.so
>  
>  
>  RPM build errors:
>  Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
>     /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_md.so-2.4.53-1.x86_64.debug
>     /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_md.so
> ```

but im not sure what to make of it

Appreciate your time and effort

Comment: What have you already tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: i added to the question what i have tried so far.

Comment: ? Why build from tar ball when SRPM's are available ? Fedora 35, `httpd-2.4.53-1.fc35.src.rpm`  https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/35/Everything/source/tree/Packages/h/httpd-2.4.53-1.fc35.src.rpm

Comment: mmm, I haven't thought about it.
how compatible is fedora3.5 with rocky 8.5 ?

Comment: I've tried it and it worked great. i built fedora rpm sources without issues although
I wonder if i did something wrong with the source tarball.